# Android: LinearLayout addView Animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-view

I currently have a working Android program that programmatically adds views to a LinearLayout. I would like those views to be animated in and cannot find any good resources on figuring out how to do this.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 27):

It's a very old question, but still interesting: you can use the attribute `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

For example:

```
<LinearLayout

                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
               />
```

Comment: Didn't know this existed. Not what i needed right now but still nice to learn something new, thanks.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty basic but it's so much better than having the views just pop up without notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

That can be done with [Scenes and Transitions API](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html).

Framework gives us three [`Transition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.html) types out of the box: [`Fade`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Fade.html), [`Slide`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Slide.html) and [`Explode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Explode.html), but you can also create your custom type of transition extending [`Visibility`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Visibility.html) class and overriding appropriate methods.

So, having any [`ViewGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), we can do this:

```
viewGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        Transition t = null;
        if (i == 1) {
            t = new Fade();
        } else if (i == 2) {
            t = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        } else if (i == 3) {
            t = TransitionInflater.from(v.getContext())
                                  .inflateTransition(R.transition.my_transition);
        }

        Button button = new Button(v.getContext());
        button.setText("My button " + i++);

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(customLayout, t);
        viewGroup.addView(button);
    }
});
```

Where **my_transition.xml** is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:duration="3000"
               android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in">

    <fade/>
    <slide android:slideEdge="bottom"/>

</transitionSet>
```

We'll get this result:

[image]

Note, that we have to perform [`TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html#beginDelayedTransition(android.view.ViewGroup)) before any change to layout has been made  (i.e. before `addView()` is called). Then framework will take care of the rest.

There is also another overload [`TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(ViewGroup)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html#beginDelayedTransition(android.view.ViewGroup)), where you do not need to specify what exact transition you want to be applied, and system will perform [`AutoTransition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/AutoTransition.html) animation, which basically will fade and change boundaries of animated view.

---

**Update** sum up from conversation in comments

Framework's [`TransitionManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html) is available from API 19, and fully supported from API 21 (by saying fully I mean e.g. [`Slide`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Slide.html) transition is available from API 21). Although there is [support package available](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/transition/package-summary.html), but it doesn't backport all the functionality. Alternatively, you can move to [TransitionsEverywhere](https://github.com/andkulikov/Transitions-Everywhere) library, which backports everything up to Android 4.0.

Comment: I want it when I add like this  `for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
 linearlayout.addView(child);
 }` how i do that?

Comment: Place `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()` before `for` loop.

Comment: I am trying to add my_transition.xml I got **@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in requires API level 21 (current min is 15)** on `  android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"`

Comment: My requirement is minimum 15 I don't want to change it.

Comment: Framework's `TransitionManager` is available from API 19, and fully supported from API 21 (by saying fully I mean e.g. `Slide` transition is available from API 21). Although there is [support package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/transition/package-summary.html) available, but it doesn't backport all the functionality. Alternatively, you can move to [`TransitionsEverywhere`](https://github.com/andkulikov/Transitions-Everywhere) library, which backports everything up to Android 4.0.

Answer (score 7):

Try

**1.** Add view to linear layout

```
linearLayout.addView(customView);
```

**2.** Add `slide_up.xml` to `res/anim` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">

  <translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**3.** Apply animation right after adding view

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_up);
customView.startAnimation(animation);
```

If you want to animate views one by one, then use following lines

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            linearLayout.addView(customView);
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_up);
           customView.startAnimation(animation);
        }
 }, 500);
```

Comment: I want slide up one after one,But this slide all customeview together.My `linearLayout.addView(customView);`  add in loop

Comment: We can achieve that by using Handler properly

Answer (score -1):

You can use ViewFlipper and set animations from there, you can take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-viewflipper)
. Good luck.