# ConstraintLayout: change constraints programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I need help with `ConstraintSet`. My goal is to change view's constraints in code, but I cant figure out how to do this right.

I have 4 `TextView`s and one `ImageView`. I need to set `ImageView` constraints to one of the `TextView`s.

```
check_answer4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.check_answer4);
check_answer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.check_answer1);
check_answer2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.check_answer2);
check_answer3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.check_answer3);

correct_answer_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.correct_answer_icon);
```

If 1st answer is right, I need to set constraints of `ImageView` to

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/check_answer1"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/check_answer1"
```

If 2nd answer is right, I need to set constraints of `ImageView` to

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/check_answer2"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/check_answer2"
```

And so on.

Comment: for this, you have to change constraint dynamically.

Comment: @shweta I'm asking exactly about this, how to do it dinamically?

Answer (score 336, accepted):

1. To set constraints of image view to:

   ```
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/check_answer1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/check_answer1"
   ```

   use:

   ```
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.imageView,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,R.id.check_answer1,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.imageView,ConstraintSet.TOP,R.id.check_answer1,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
   ```
2. To set constraints of image view to:

   ```
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/check_answer2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/check_answer2"
   ```

   use:

   ```
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout); 
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.imageView,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,R.id.check_answer2,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);      
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.imageView,ConstraintSet.TOP,R.id.check_answer2,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
   ```

Comment: constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout); in this line, is constraintLayout the parent layout?

Comment: @Pang `.clone(constraintLayout)` what is this variable and where do I get it from?

Comment: @ReejeshPK @MiXT4PE Yes it IS the parent layout, i.e.
`ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);`

Comment: @leonheess I think that should be a variable referencing your Constraint Layout ViewGroup

Comment: Is it done with animation effect or not, and if not, how to do this with animation effect?

Comment: How about if the view is a floating window manager with no id? I tried to change the id with the view but it doesn't work, because it must be an integer.

Comment: where to get those ID? IDs are not defined before hand. View.generateViewId()

Answer (score 149):

Assume we want to change constraints during runtime, making button1 to be aligned with button2 when clicked:

[image]

Then, having this layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Button 3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.223" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

We can do following:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button1.setOnClickListener {
            val params = button1.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
            params.leftToRight = button2.id
            params.topToTop = button2.id
            params.bottomToBottom = button2.id
            button1.requestLayout()
        }
    }
```

Comment: My friend, I don't get your code.. what is `layoutParams` and `val`? Is this even Java?

Comment: Sir, it's kotlin programming language. Java equivalent will be `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) button1.getLayoutParams();`

Comment: I think you forgot to write  button1.layoutParams = params

Comment: @sumitsonawane, it's not needed, because we are mutating that instance and after that we perform `button1.requestLayout()` which then will inspect the instance of `LayoutParams` that we have mutated.

Comment: assume I have a custom view, inside the custom view layout there are Button (with id @+id/btn) and ImageView(with id @+id/imageView), then I add my custom view into my activity layout, in my activity layout, I have TextView, how about changing the TextView constraint to View inside my customView?
I tried your solution but it didn't work

Comment: @azizbekian, it might be strange, but for me it didn't work without assigning new layoutParams object to the View.

Comment: @qwertyfinger, indeed strange, because `setLayoutParams()` will eventually call `requestLayout()`.

Comment: @azizbekian, yes, for me the final solution is replacing `requestLayout()` call with `setLayoutParams()` and then it works. Simply mutating `layoutParams` and requesting layout myself doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: How do you unset some constraints? Say I don't want the left side of the button to be constrained to anything.

Comment: This solution works for me. One more little thing, how can I make it with animation

Comment: @ScofieldTran, as simple as performing `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()`  before layout parameters. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43629482/1083957).

Comment: It's enough to call `setLayoutParams()` , method `requestLayout()` is calling inside it.

Answer (score 121):

Another approach is to update the layout params of view like this (without requesting Layout):

```
yourView.updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> {
        startToEnd = targetView.id
        topToTop = targetView.id
        bottomToBottom = targetView.id
        //add other constraints if needed
      }
```

Comment: Wow. I had no idea `View.updateLayoutParams` was a native extension. This makes updating layout parameters programmatically much more clean and readable.

Comment: Resolved my problem. Thank you, your code very clean and goal

Answer (score 27):

In addition to [azizbekian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45265164/7114988), let me point out two things:

1. If left/right didn't work, try start/end like this:

`params.startToEnd = button2.id`

2. If you want to remove a constraint, use UNSET flag like this:

`params.startToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.UNSET`

Comment: `UNSET` is very useful and helped with an issue I was having

Answer (score 14):

In Kotlin you can simply extend `ConstraintSet` class and add some methods to take advantage of dsl in Kotlin and produce a more readable code.
Like this

```
class KotlinConstraintSet : ConstraintSet() {

    companion object {
        inline fun buildConstraintSet(block:KotlinConstraintSet.()->Unit) =
            KotlinConstraintSet().apply(block)
    }
    //add this if you plan on using the margin param in ConstraintSet.connect
    var margin: Int? = null
        get() {
            val result = field
            margin = null //reset it to work with other constraints
            return result
        }

    inline infix fun Unit.and(other: Int) = other // just to join two functions

    inline infix fun Int.topToBottomOf(bottom: Int) =
        margin?.let {
            connect(this, TOP, bottom, BOTTOM, it)
        } ?: connect(this, TOP, bottom, BOTTOM)

    inline fun margin(margin: Int) {
        this.margin = margin
    }

    inline infix fun Int.bottomToBottomOf(bottom: Int) =
        margin?.let {
            connect(this, BOTTOM, bottom, BOTTOM, it)
        } ?: connect(this, BOTTOM, bottom, BOTTOM)

    inline infix fun Int.topToTopOf(top: Int) =
        margin?.let {
            connect(this, TOP, top, TOP, it)
        } ?: connect(this, TOP, top, TOP)

    inline infix fun Int.startToEndOf(end: Int) =
        margin?.let {
            connect(this, START, end, END, it)
        } ?: connect(this, START, end, END)

            ...
    //TODO generate other functions depending on your needs

    infix fun Int.clear(constraint: Constraints) =
        when (constraint) {
            Constraints.TOP -> clear(this, TOP)
            Constraints.BOTTOM -> clear(this, BOTTOM)
            Constraints.END -> clear(this, END)
            Constraints.START -> clear(this, START)
        }

    //inline infix fun clearTopCon
    inline infix fun appliesTo(constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout) =
        applyTo(constraintLayout)

    inline infix fun clones(constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout) =
        clone(constraintLayout)

    inline fun constraint(view: Int, block: Int.() -> Unit) =
        view.apply(block)
}

enum class Constraints {
    TOP, BOTTOM, START, END //you could add other values to use with the clear fun like LEFT
}
```

And use it like this

```
        buildConstraintSet {
            this clones yourConstraintLayout
            constraint(R.id.view1) {
                margin(value:Int) and this topToBottomOf R.id.view2
                margin(30) and this bottomToBottomOf ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID
            }
            constraint(R.id.view2) {
                this clear Constraints.BOTTOM
                margin(0) and this topToTopOf R.id.topGuide
            }
            constraint(R.id.view4) {
                this topToTopOf R.id.view2
                this bottomToBottomOf R.id.view3
                this startToEndOf R.id.view2
            }
            //or you could simply do
            R.id.view1 startToEndOf R.view2
            R.id.view1 toptToBottomOf R.view3
            R.id.view3 bottomtToBottomOf R.view2
            R.id.view3 clear Constraints.END

            // and finally call applyTo()
            this appliesTo yourConstraintLayout
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

**I know my answer is very late, yet I'm sure It'd help others that stop by here a lot.
This article is not mine but I made a few changes, that being said, you should endeavor to check out the full article [here](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Managing_Constraints_using_ConstraintSet)**

### Constraint Sets

The key to working with constraint sets in Java code is the ConstraintSet class. This class contains a range of methods that allow tasks such as creating, configuring and applying constraints to a ConstraintLayout instance. In addition, the current constraints for a ConstraintLayout instance may be copied into a ConstraintSet object and used to apply the same constraints to other layouts (with or without modifications).

A ConstraintSet instance is created just like any other Java object:

```
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
```

Once a constraint set has been created, methods can be called on the instance to perform a wide range of tasks.
The following code configures a constraint set in which the left-hand side of a Button view is connected to the right-hand side of an EditText view with a margin of 70dp:

```
set.connect(button1.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 
        editText1.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 70);
```

Applying Constraints to a Layout
Once the constraint set is configured, it must be applied to a ConstraintLayout instance before it will take effect. A constraint set is applied via a call to the applyTo() method, passing through a reference to the layout object to which the settings are to be applied:

```
set.applyTo(myLayout);
```

There are lot more stuffs you can do with the `ConstraintSet` API, Setting horizontal and vertical bias, center horizontally and vertically, manipulate Chains and a lot more.

Really nice read.

Again, this is just an adaptation.

Answer (score 6):

You can create constraints into `ConstraintLayout` with `ConstraintSet` or `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` properties.

I created a `ConstraintSet` kotlin extension for simple usage.
This is simple and robust.

#### Usage

```kotlin
 applyConstraint {
            centerHorizontallyParent(imageView)
            centerHorizontallyParent(textView)
            topToParent(imageView, px(12))
            topToBottom(textView, imageView, px(4))
        }
```

#### Code

```kotlin
fun ConstraintLayout.applyConstraint(block: ConstraintSet.() -> Unit) {
    ConstraintSet().apply {
        clone(this@applyConstraint)
        block(this)
    }.applyTo(this)
}

fun ConstraintSet.centerParent(v1: View) {
    centerHorizontallyParent(v1)
    centerVerticallyParent(v1)
}

fun ConstraintSet.centerHorizontallyParent(v1: View) {
    centerHorizontally(v1.id, PARENT_ID)
}

fun ConstraintSet.centerVerticallyParent(v1: View) {
    centerVertically(v1.id, PARENT_ID)
}

fun ConstraintSet.topToTop(v1: View, v2: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, TOP, v2.id, TOP, margin)
}

fun ConstraintSet.topToParent(v1: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, TOP, PARENT_ID, TOP, margin)
}

fun ConstraintSet.bottomToBottom(v1: View, v2: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, BOTTOM, v2.id, BOTTOM, margin)
}

fun ConstraintSet.bottomToParent(v1: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, BOTTOM, PARENT_ID, BOTTOM, margin)
}

fun ConstraintSet.topToBottom(v1: View, v2: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, TOP, v2.id, BOTTOM, margin)
}

fun ConstraintSet.bottomToTop(v1: View, v2: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, BOTTOM, v2.id, TOP, margin)
}

fun ConstraintSet.startToStart(v1: View, v2: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, START, v2.id, START, margin)
}

fun ConstraintSet.startToParent(v1: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, START, PARENT_ID, START, margin)
}

fun ConstraintSet.endToEnd(v1: View, v2: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, END, v2.id, END, margin)
}

fun ConstraintSet.endToParent(v1: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, END, PARENT_ID, END, margin)
}

fun ConstraintSet.startToEnd(v1: View, v2: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, START, v2.id, END, margin)
}

fun ConstraintSet.endToStart(v1: View, v2: View, @Px margin: Int = 0) {
    connect(v1.id, END, v2.id, START, margin)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [TransitionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager) to animate the changes:

```
public static void animateConstraintLayout(ConstraintLayout constraintLayout, ConstraintSet set, long duration) {
    AutoTransition trans = new AutoTransition();
    trans.setDuration(duration);
    trans.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout, trans);
    set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
}
```

You can call it like this after updating the layout with ConstraintSet:

```
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(constraintLayout);
set.connect(R.id.example, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.anotherExample, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
set.connect(R.id.example, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.anotherExample, ConstraintSet.TOP);

animateConstraintLayout(constraintLayout, set, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

**@vishakha yeolekar** 's solution does not work for me.

To change constraints, we need to follow these steps:

- **clone** parent layout
- **clear** previous constraint
- **connect** constraint
- **apply** constraint to parent layout

### Solution code (in Kotlin)

```
val clParent = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.parent_layout)
val mConstraintSet = ConstraintSet()
mConstraintSet.clone(clParent)
mConstraintSet.clear(R.id.imageView, ConstraintSet.END)
mConstraintSet.connect(R.id.imageView, ConstraintSet.END, R.id.check_answer, ConstraintSet.END)
mConstraintSet.applyTo(clParent)
```

Here is the link for more info and methods of ConstraintSet - [Click Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet).

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf = "parentView"
```

If you liked to declared it with programe, it will be...

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.rightToRight = parentView.getId()
```

If you used programe to declared the parentview(viewgroup), don't forget to give the parentview a generated id.

```
parentView.setId(View.generatedId());
```