# Android : Constraint Layout Set Constraint top programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I have 3 views : A,B,C. (A and B are equal in height) At the beginning B's visibility is gone and C's top constraint is the bottom of A , so C appears below A. After some time I change the visibility of A to gone and B to visible. What happens is that C is dragged to the top because A's visibility is gone. What I want to do is set the top constraint of C to the bottom of B. How can I do this? I need to do it programmatically.

Here is where I am now currently ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
 //A
<LinearLayout

    android:onClick="clickedOnRecordLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/record_layout_top_margin"
    android:id="@+id/record_button_layout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_of_record_button"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/red_circle_drawable"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/radius_of_record_button"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/radius_of_record_button">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/record_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_microphone"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/record_image_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/record_image_dimen" />
</LinearLayout>

 //B - initially its visibility is gone
<LinearLayout
    android:onClick="clickedOnStartedRecordingLayout"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/record_layout_top_margin"
    android:id="@+id/started_button_layout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_of_record_button"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/red_circle_drawable"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/radius_of_record_button"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/radius_of_record_button">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stop_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stop_recording"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/record_image_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/record_image_dimen" />
</LinearLayout>


//C
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tap_text_top_margin"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/record_button_layout"
    android:id="@+id/tap_on_microphone_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@string/tap_to_start_message"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/chronometer"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Please take a look at this it may give you the idea, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263159/constraintlayout-change-constraints-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to use **ConstraintSet**, but if you like to keep it simple I would like to bring to your notice

> ConstraintLayout has a specific handling of widgets being marked as View.GONE.
>
> GONE widgets, as usual, are not going to be displayed and are not part
>   of the layout itself (i.e. their actual dimensions will not be changed
>   if marked as GONE).
>
> But in terms of the layout computations, GONE widgets are still part
>   of it, with an important distinction:
>
> For the layout pass, their dimension will be considered as zero
>   (basically, they will be resolved to a point) If they have constraints
>   to other widgets they will still be respected, but any margins will be
>   as if equals to zero
>   Check it out [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)

Let me demonstrate with a simple layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <EditText     // View A
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:hint="email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText // View B
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:hint="password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />
    <EditText   //View C
        android:id="@+id/otp"
        android:hint="otp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This layout looks like

[image: All fields visible]

When you set the **email** field i.e view A to gone

[image: View A visibility GONE here]

When you set **password** to GONE, i.e View B

[image: View B visibility is GONE]

This is the magic of Constraint layout.