# Android ConstraintLayout - Top constraint for two layout

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, android-constraintlayout

I am stuck with ConstraintLayout and confused to use which property to do as I want.

As per the following image, I wanted to give top-constraint of `Details` to either `TextView` of `OrderTakenBy` or `OrderCollectedBy` as per the height of that view.

[image]

Scenario:

If I give top constraint of **Detail** view as the bottom of **OrderTakenBy** TextView, It will overlap (as below image) the view of **OrderCollectedBy** Textview if it gets more lines. Vice versa.

[image]

Note: **Order Taken By** or **Order Collected By** may contain two or three lines.

So what can I do for top constraints which can work for both dynamic heights?

### Edited:

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                tools:context=".activity.AccountMasterAddActivity"
                tools:showIn="@layout/activity_account_master_add">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/hint_order_no"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/supplierNameTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/supplierNameTextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/orderNoTextView"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                    tools:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/hint_supplier_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/supplierNameTextView"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
                    tools:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="@string/hint_order_date"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/supplierNameTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/orderDateTextView"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
                    tools:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/hint_order_taken_by"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/orderNoTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderNoTextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/orderTakenByTextView"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="TextView TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="@string/hint_order_collected_by"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/orderDateTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/orderDateTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView8" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/orderCollectedByTextView"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
                    tools:text="TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/hint_details"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/orderCollectedByTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/orderTakenByTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orderCollectedByTextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detailsTextView"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:autoLink="phone"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView12"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView12"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12"
                    tools:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/productLabel"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Products"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/detailsTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/detailsTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detailsTextView" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                    android:id="@+id/guideline"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/productLabel"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/productLabel"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/productLabel" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: conect top of Detail view to bottom of last textview of OrderCollectedbyBy

Comment: If I give top constraint of Detail view as bottom of OrderCollectedbyBy TextView, It will overlap (as below image) the view of  OrderTakenBy Textview if it gets more lines.

Comment: use a container like a linear layout on the tvs below ordercollected  maybe also a scrollview and add your textviews there

Comment: or you need to set contrainst while adding the tvs like this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45264822/8528047

Comment: Can I do it with `ConstraintLayout` only?

Comment: ya sure with constraint layout I am saying either wrap the tvs under ordercollected in a linear layout or set the constraints progmatically

Comment: you have to use barrier for that. If you share some code I will add answer using barrier.

Comment: barrier take top constraint automatically as per height of that view

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the **Barrier** To overcome this issue.

A Barrier references multiple widgets as input, and creates a virtual guideline based on the most extreme widget on the specified side. For example, a left barrier will align to the left of all the referenced views.

Here is the Documentation for [Barrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Barrier)

Add **Order Taken By or Order Collected By** as `app:constraint_referenced_ids="view1,view2"` and set the **Detail view** top to the bottom of the Barrie.

**XML Reference:**

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="411dp"
    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="order_taken_by,order_collected_by"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="21dp"/>


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_16sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier"/>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

> Use bottom barrier 
>   Use **Deatils** textview top constraint to barrier and barrier reference to **OrderTakenBy**, **OrderCollectedBy** textview.
>
> [image: Blockquote]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OrderTakenBy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="warehouse sdgjklsdj jgkjskg"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/OrderCollectedBy"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OrderCollectedBy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="hospital fhkhsf "
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/OrderTakenBy"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="bottom"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="OrderCollectedBy, OrderTakenBy" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Details"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="lorem_ipsum"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: this is exactly what i want although the above answer is same but was unable to get from that answer thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think you can wrap `order taken by` and `order collected by` in another `constraint layout` or to check programmatically the height(after setting the text) of the `TextView's` and change programmatically the top constraint.