# How to break constraint circle and re initialize in constraintlayout in Android

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I have created circle constraint via programmatically, now i have to break that constraint and reinitialize with different angle,Please help me out this

```
final ConstraintLayout cl = layoutRoot.findViewById(R.id.circle_constraint);
final ConstraintSet c = new ConstraintSet();
c.clone(cl);
c.constrainCircle(R.id.tvStartTime, R.id.imgCenter,100,60);
c.applyTo(cl);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you show us some code?

Comment: Edited question

Comment: I want to apply again constraint to tvStartTime with different angle

Comment: Have you looked into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263159/constraintlayout-change-constraints-programmatically

Comment: checked already, but i want to clear constraint and reassign angle in certain time

Comment: So you want just the last parameter to change? I presume the radius will remain the same.

Comment: Yes, I want to change only angle in certain time, for that i have to break constraint, what you think?

Comment: I think this what you need. https://android.jlelse.eu/constraintlayout-in-the-limelight-6c22b54d9726#4e94
It uses the setRotation method