# Is it possible to make an ImageView cover the whole screen, if it's contained in a fragment in a ViewPager that doesn't cover the whole screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-constraintlayout

I am using a `ViewPager` in an activity layout which is a `ConstraintLayout`. This `ViewPager` is constrained in order to be displayed below a sibling widget. This `ViewPager`, so, doesn't cover the whole screen.

However, in the fragments of this `ViewPager`, there is an `ImageView` that must be displayed covering the whole screen. This `ImageView` is unique per fragment of this `ViewPager` (implying that each `ImageView` must actually be contained in each `ViewPager`'s fragments).

The problem is: since this `ImageView` is within the fragments of the `ViewPager` that doesn't cover the whole screen, then it's impossible to use something like `match_parent` for this `ImageView`, since it will match the `ViewPager` which, obviously, doesn't cover all the screen (since it's shown below a sibling widget).

What could I do to make the `ImageView` fill the whole screen?

Answer (score 1):

When you show the imageView fragment in view pager you can change your constraints programmatically. Here there is simple example for this

[ConstraintLayout: change constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263159/constraintlayout-change-constraints-programmatically)

Comment: I'm trying it but it appears that it's impossible to programatically define constraints between a `ViewPager`'s item's widget and a container's widget (container that contains also the `ViewPager`).

Comment: I think you have to change all viewPager constraints as matchConstraint for all screen when you open the imageView

Answer (score 1):

> fragment.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> viewpger_item.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgPool"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"` used on the `Viewpager` will impede the `ImageView` from covering the whole screen, no?

Comment: you can remove that margin. I add this code from my working code that's why it's there

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I actually need to set the `ViewPager`'s item's `ImageView` covering the screen, BUT the `ViewPager` must not cover the whole screen (so the `margin` was good, but your solution didn't fix the problem). I think it's not possible. However I really must do this UI. I'm trying another thing and I will create a new question.