# align root view of layout to right or end edge of view

Tags: android

I have a layout with width of 200dp. And I want to align this layout (LinearLayout in that case) to right or left corner of my recyclerview, based in info of my view. How I can do that? I cant create an another layout inside this layout and align it.

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="data"
        type="com.package.service.home.ui.Message" />

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.package.service.home.ui.MyViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/user"
        app:data="@{data}"
        app:viewModel="@{viewModel}" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/file"
        app:data="@{data}"
        app:viewModel="@{viewModel}" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/status"
        app:data="@{data}"
        app:viewModel="@{viewModel}" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what about using constraint set in ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Yes, I can change my Linearlayout to something else. But will it solve a problem? Can you put an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263159/constraintlayout-change-constraints-programmatically

Comment: If I correctly understood this approach, its moves all items inside view. But I want to move whole view to the right or left, not separate items