# How to set constraintTop_toTopOf attribute from MainActivity.kt for dynamically created TextView

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a very basic card game. I want to create a bunch of `TextView`s dynamicly in `MainActivity.kt` to be stacked on the exact position of another TextView as a placeholder, that was created in the `activity_main.xml`
I need to be able to move these objects to different positions by changing the position constraints.

I searched the docs but could not find how to set the constraints programatically during runtime.
Setting x and y does not work because I'm using constraints.

How to set tv's constraint to be placeholder's top and margin? Something like:

```
tv.layoutParams.topToTopOf = "@id/deck_placeholder"
tv.layoutParams.marginLeft = "10dp"
```

to achieve what the xml sets below

```
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/deck_placeholder"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/deck_placeholder"
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deck_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="DD"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.main_layout)
        val placeholder = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.deck_placeholder)
        for (i in 1..52) {
            var tv = TextView(this)
            tv.text = i.toString()
            tv.id = generateViewId()
            //TODO: how to set constraint and position here
            //tv.layoutParams = placeholder.layoutParams
            layout.addView(tv)
        }
    }
}
```

The results are as shown here. The generated TextViews should be on the right side of the screen where DD is.

[image: emulator screen left]

I tried to copy the layout parameters of the placeholder and the cards are on the right place,  but how can I move it to another place later by specifying the constraints and margins?

[image: emulator screen right]

Or is there a better Layout to use so I can put X and Y coordinates but is still responsive to different screen sizes/orientation?

Using Android Studio 4.1.3 with Kotlin.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConstraintLayout: change constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263159/constraintlayout-change-constraints-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks, but that question and the answer is for java. There is some kotlin answers but did not work as expected. I tried to work it out but it didn't not move my objects to the right place.. Using the java code would crash at null pointers.
I have read a few java solutions but still could not work it out with kotlin.

Comment: Well you can find Kotlin code if you do a search. Like this: https://www.journaldev.com/291/android-constraintlayout-kotlin. If you're having issues with it, then *that* should be what your question is about, not trying to find an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks, this example works.
I did search many times but could not find this exact article, possibly wrong keywords.. You are good! I'm still new with android.
My problem was partly because I tried to set the constraints _before_ adding it to the layout.