# How to overlap an image on textview programmatically in constraintlayout?

Tags: android, android-studio

Im making a mental math app(this is my first app) and if user inputs correct number, i want it programmatically add a red circle on TextView in ScrollView like the image below. How can i acheive this in constraintralout? I searched for similar questions but nothing solved mine. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: is your circle an image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45264822/8190327 check this answer

Comment: Yes but if the result can be like the image above, everythings fine for me.

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan Using the way you posted, if i place the circle on TextView(user's input) in ScrollView and scroll down, would the circle move with theTextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quiet simple.

First Make an item with the any layout as follows:

(I have used Constraint layout, you can use relative or any thing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="56"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red_circle_image_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/number_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/number_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/number_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/number_text_view"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML Code For Red Circle: `@drawable/circle`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
</shape>
```

The above code will create a view like the below image:

[image]

Now Reference the Textview and ImageView using Java or Kotlin:

Java:

```
TextView numberTV = findViewByID(R.id.number_text_view);
ImageView circleImgV = findViewByID(R.id.red_circle_image_view);
```

Kotlin:

```
val numberTV = findViewByID(R.id.number_text_view)
val circleImgV = findViewByID(R.id.red_circle_image_view)
```

You will need a on click listener where you will be toggling the visibility of the `circleImgV`

```
View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.number_text_view){
                if (circleImgV.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                    circleImgV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    circleImgV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Now Set The on click listener to `numberTV`:

```
numberTV.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

**Changing the inside numbers have to be done via code in java or kotlin**

Now Keep Reusing the above code for generating Complex views as follows or do it via code or use it recycler view (I am only showing an option) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include3"
        layout="@layout/stackoverflow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/include4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/stackoverflow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/include3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include2" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include4"
        layout="@layout/stackoverflow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include3" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        layout="@layout/stackoverflow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/include"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

*My Layout name is stackoverflow.xml*

Comment: Thanks. Would this way work if the textview is in scrollview and scroll down? Would the circle come with the TextView?