# ImageView constraintlayout bottom

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to assign double `bottom_toBottomOf` in an `ImageView`?
I have a layout that I have something like a `FloatingActionButton` and I want to be always above of my two views. I started doing the list and it works because I've added in the `FAB` `bottom_toBottomOf="idRecyclerView"` but the problem is now that I've added another view, the `FAB` doesn't put above of that view because it's aligned to the recyclerView.

Note :
RecyclerView and View are `visibility=gone` since start, depending on the data I enable the `RecyclerView` or the `View` so, when I initialise the `RecyclerView` it works and the `FAB` is above of the list, but when I initialise the `View` the button remains to the bottom because the `RecyclerView` is gone (aligned to the bottom).

This is an example of what I have right now
[image]

When I have the list since the FAB has the `bottom_bottomOf=recycler` it works, but when I show the `View` the FAB is in the bottom, and I'm wondering if is there any way to add like double `bottom_bottomOf` so always the FAB will stay above the view no matter if it's the recyclerView or the View

Comment: Please ask the question properly, so I can help. Share the images for reference like what you want and what you have. I don't even know where your `RecyclerView` is?

Comment: Use a barrier that is on top of the two view. See [Barrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Barrier).

Comment: bottom_bottomOf ="parent" to the fab..

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the position of your FAB dynamically, in that case you need to achieve this programmatically. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45264822/19576538) to learn how to change view constrains in code. Execute it right after changing the visibility of your views.